# What could be a reason for org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-7:jnlp-download-servlet failure?

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, jnlp, maven-webstart-plugin

Our pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.our</groupId>
    <artifactId>our.control</artifactId>
    <version>1.20.2.7</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>our.gui-client.webstart</artifactId>
  <name>our.gui-client.webstart</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>webstatic</directory>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.html</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
              <directory>webstatic</directory>
              <filtering>false</filtering>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>webstart-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jnlp-download-servlet</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectoryName>webstart</outputDirectoryName>
          <outputJarVersions>false</outputJarVersions>
          <jnlpFiles>
            <jnlpFile>
              <templateFilename>template.vm</templateFilename>
              <outputFilename>our.jnlp</outputFilename>
              <jarResources>
                <jarResource>
                  <groupId>com.our</groupId>
                  <artifactId>our.gui-client</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <mainClass>com.our.control.guiclient.MainApp</mainClass>
                </jarResource>
              </jarResources>
            </jnlpFile>
          </jnlpFiles>
          <sign>
            <keystore>${project.build.directory}/keyStore</keystore>
            <keypass>our</keypass>
            <storepass>our</storepass>
            <alias>webstart</alias>

            <storetype>jks</storetype>
            <validity>3650</validity>
            <dnameCn>our.com</dnameCn>
            <dnameOu>None</dnameOu>
            <dnameO>SIA</dnameO>
            <dnameL>L</dnameL>
            <dnameSt>St</dnameSt>
            <dnameC>C</dnameC>

            <keystoreConfig>
              <delete>true</delete>
              <gen>true</gen>
            </keystoreConfig>

            <verify>true</verify>
          </sign>
          <updateManifestEntries>
            <Trusted-Library>true</Trusted-Library>
            <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
            <Codebase>*</Codebase>
          </updateManifestEntries>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and the stacktrace is

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-7:jnlp-download-servlet (default) on project our.control.gui-client.webstart: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-7:jnlp-download-servlet failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:webstart-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-7:jnlp-download-servlet failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.util.DefaultArtifactUtil.artifactContainsClass (DefaultArtifactUtil.java:211)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.resolveJarResources (JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.webstart.JnlpDownloadServletMojo.execute (JnlpDownloadServletMojo.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:827)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:272)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :our.control.gui-client.webstart
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case appears if the circular dependency is taking place!

```
<jarResources>
                <jarResource>
                  <groupId>com.our</groupId>
                  <artifactId>our.gui-client</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
                  <mainClass>com.our.control.guiclient.MainApp</mainClass>
                </jarResource>
              </jarResources>
```

this jar was reffering another pom, that was reffering the current pom of the interes. So, technically it works like a circular jar, but unfortunately the error message isn't comprehensive